# BehaviorSubject not allowing to store data in Array after subscription

Tags: html, arrays, typescript

Hello guys first time asking a question here. I hope it's well-written enough :)

Let's go directly to the problem.
I've got a question about a behaviorSubject variable in typescript which is not allowing me to store data in the arrays of a service after calling a backend's API (PHP). Here's the code of the main function:

```
public notificationsGeneral: BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> ([]);
public notificationsPublic: BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> ([]);
public notificationsPrivate: BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> ([]);
public notificationsAll: BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<TemplateNotificationModel[]> ([]);


public getUserNotifications(userId: number): void{
    this.http.get<TemplateNotificationModel[]>(this.BACKEND_URL + 'notifications/user/' + userId).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.notificationsAll.next(data);
            this.notificationsAll.subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.sortNotifications(data);
                }
            )
        },
        (error) =>{
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
    console.log("2º " + this.notificationsPrivate.getValue())
/*
Result here is: 2º
*/
```

Here is sortNotifications():

```
sortNotifications(data: any){
    
    var gen = [] 
    var pub = []
    var priv = []
    
    for(let element of data){
      switch(element.notification_type.id){
        case NotificationTypes.GENERAL:
            gen.push(element);
        break;
        case NotificationTypes.PUBLIC:
            pub.push(element);
        break;
        case NotificationTypes.PRIVATE:
            priv.push(element);
        break;
      }
    } 
    
    this.notificationsPublic.next(pub);
    this.notificationsGeneral.next(gen);
    this.notificationsPrivate.next(priv);
    console.log("1º " + this.notificationsPrivate.getValue())
/*
Result here is 
1º [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

*/
    }
```

The console.log who has the "1º" is returning arrays filled with the data that I want but the console log outside the subscribe (the one which has the "2º") is returning empty array.

I don't know if I'm missing out something basic about coding but I'm not doing any operation that can erase the data in that array. So why is this happening ?

Thanks a lot!

PD:

1- I must store the data into those arrays because there are more functions in the service that are going to read that data.

2- I'm using behaviourSubject because there are components that will be subscribed to the getters functions of those arrays and must detect and update changes whenever the are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a classic one.

Here, you call an asynchronous function.

```
this.http.get<TemplateNotificationModel[]>(this.BACKEND_URL + 'notifications/user/' + userId)
```

JavaScript does not wait for it's result to return and just proceeds with the following code. Which is

```
console.log("2º " + this.notificationsPrivate.getValue())
```

So what happens here is, that `console.log(2º)` gets called at a point in time when the array still is empty. Some millis later the async function gets its result from server and `console.log("1º")` gets called.

The order in your console should always be first 2º then 1º, which underlines my assumption.